# How to find expectation value from probability density?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

How to find expectation value from a given probability density?

E.g. given to find expectation value of $x^2$ from probability density $\rho(x)= 1/(2(hx)^{1/2}) $.

This is not a homework question, I just want to understand how to solve questions like this, you may use your own example.

Comment: Would [statistics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 2):

According to expected value [basic properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Basic_properties):
$$ {\displaystyle \operatorname {E} [g(X)]=\int _{\mathbb {R} }g(x)f(x)\,dx.} $$
it should be :
$$ 
E[x^2] = \int x^2\,\frac{1}{{{2}{\sqrt{{h}{x}}}}}\,dx
$$